# Importing torch failed when lazyimported cv2 first

Tags: opencv, torch, tensorlayer

I am using self-compiled python 3.6.3 ([link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-363/)) on Ubuntu 14.04. My torch is `1.0.1.post2`, Tensorlayer `1.10.1`. To reproduce my issue, try with

```
from tensorlayer.lazy_imports import LazyImport
cv2 = LazyImport("cv2")
import torch
```

It fails with,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
```

My torch is installed with `pip install torch torchvision`. Also before compiling Python, I did `apt-get install tk8.6-dev` in order to make python configured with `tkinter`. The reason why I compile Python on my own is that shipped `apt-get install`-ed Python is incompatible with tkinter somehow, even with packages installed, it errs at importing too.

I wish not to change the importing order at it surely works. I hope to find out the real cause of it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some old posts, where they change the order or import cv2 again after tensorflow. Have you tried that?

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari sure, it won't work. I upgraded py3.6.3 to py3.6.4 and the error disappears.